# Is there a ROM of Android 8 or higher for the ASUS_X00ID Asus 4 Max?

Tags: custom-roms, rom, rom-update

Does anyone know if there is a ROM of Android 8 or higher for the cellphone Asus 4 Max?

If it does not exist, will be an official update for this model of cellphone?

Comment: i cannot see any roms in xda forum

Comment: I didn't find it too. I was thinking if they will release the Android 8 for the Asus 4 Max...

Comment: Please post a question in xda forum that request a oreo or pixel based rom. Hope somebody would build it, because lineage 14.1 is available there.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/in/support/FAQ/1035681/ Asus oreo upgrade plan in India.